# Android show download progress after finishing activity

Tags: multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-progressbar, activity-finish

Hi in my chat application i have been downloading media files from listview. i had used thead for doing download operation. It works fine and shows the progress status when we stays in the same activity. If we finished the activity and come again how could i show the progress of download from last position. I can see that downloading happening in the background, but i need to show that status in UI.. Is it possible with thread..Do i need to use any other approach..?

I have tried with normal thread.. Is Asynchtask can do the needfull..?

Comment: @Iamsomeone the thread code part is posted below.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my thread 


@Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(task.url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
            if (chunk.end != 0) // support unresumable links
                connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + chunk.begin + "-" + chunk.end);

            connection.connect();
            File cf = new File(FileUtils.address(task.save_address, String.valueOf(chunk.id)));
            InputStream remoteFileIn = connection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream chunkFile = new FileOutputStream(cf, true);

            int len = 0;
            // set watchDoger to stop thread after 1sec if no connection lost
            watchDog = new ConnectionWatchDog(5000, this);
            watchDog.start();
            while (!this.isInterrupted() &&  
                    (len = remoteFileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                watchDog.reset();
                chunkFile.write(buffer, 0, len);
                process(len);
            }

            chunkFile.flush();
            chunkFile.close();
            watchDog.interrupt();
            connection.disconnect();

            if (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                observer.rebuild(chunk);
            }


        }catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            observer.connectionLost(task.id);
            puaseRelatedTask();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;
    }

process(len) will send progress status to the UI using interface callbacks.
```

Answer (score 0):

- The easy way: Use Fragments, so Activity isn't closed.
- The hard way:
  Use Service and Intents.

And generally I think it is not good to have running threads while an activity is paused. It could be destroyed by OS while your thread is running. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle